# How can I find the person whose age is known in the Pandas library?

Tags: python

I was working on patients with diabetes at the Pandas library. Now I found the age of the oldest, it was 81. Now how do I find this 81 year old person? I want to be able to see other values ​​as well.

i tried that:

```
Age_max= np.max(diabet['Age'].unique())
Print(age_max)
output=81
##Now, i want to find 81 yo frend.

diabet[age_max]
output= errno
```

Answer (score 1):

`diabet.loc[diabet['age'] == age_max]` should do the trick.

Also, you can simply getting the max age with just `age_max = diabet['age'].max()`

Comment: @Ghassen Sultana: bro i tried this, but output error

Comment: diabet.loc[diabet['age'] == age_max]   working this

Comment: @SapphireCantos "but output error" **what error**?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
diabet[diabet[age_max] == 81 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Filter the data to include only the 81-year-old patients
filtered_data = diabet[diabet['age'] == 81]

# filtered_data that contains only the rows where the age is 81
print(filtered_data)
```